# resources for building a dragonborn bard?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, bard

I am currently trying to build a level 1 dragonborn bard.

I need assistance finding the resources that contain the information on class and racial feats, powers for race and class as well as modifiers from the race and the class choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Bard handbook, [Cruel Lullabies](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2402306). It discusses both original bards and skalds, and presents powers and feat choices within a singular rating framework. For discussion on how to actually fill in the character sheet, we have a [number of questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e+character-sheets) exploring the more opaque parts of the sheets. Beyond that, I recommend reading the Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms, as its discussion of building bards from scratch is quite good. There is also a fairly underwhelming [dragonborn handbook](http://community.wizards.com/forum/4e-character-optimization/threads/1974071), but it does discuss dragonborn specific options in some detail.